# How to cache audio for offline use in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application in which I need to get the specified audio file from my website when the user plays it, but I don't want to stream it or download it every time, just the first time. So I was thinking of caching it and play offline whenever the user is in need. So please suggest any method to do so. Or if exists any other method rather than caching `like downloading the actual file to file storage and play whenever needed`.

Comment: You can build a database cache using `Retrofit` and `Room`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to cache files, you should use createTempFile(). For example, the following method extracts the file name from a URL and creates a file with that name in your app's internal cache directory:

```
private File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
    File file;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, 
context.getCacheDir());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error while creating file
    }
    return file;
}
```

You can also see here for more about caching files.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteCacheFileInternal

Hope this will help.

Comment: Or just write it to internal storage-  all depends on if you want caching behavior controlled by the OS or not.  I tend to use storage so that its more predictable.

Comment: @GabeSechan, May I know how this can be done? Could you direct me to some online resources or SO posts?